# Kendo Slider change event parameter undefined

Tags: user-interface, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have multiple kendo sliders on a page. When the value of a slider changes, I want to identify what slider triggered the change event so that I can change its color based on the value selected.

```
<div id="div_slider">
    <input id="slider1" data-bind="kendoSlider: { value: myValue, min: 0, max: 5,change: changeSlider }" />
    <input id="slider2" data-bind="kendoSlider: { value: myValue,  min: 0, max: 5,change: changeSlider }" />
    <input id="slider3" data-bind="kendoSlider: { value: myValue,  min: 0, max: 5,change: changeSlider }" />
</div>
```

I have my knockout bindings as following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ViewModel = function () {
        this.myValue = 5;

        this.changeSlider = function(data, event) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(event);
        };
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

The problem is that the event parameter of the slider change function is always undefined. Does any one have any ideas why ?

Comment: And what about `this` inside your `changeSlider`? Try to log  `console.log(this);`

Comment: yea that's correct, used this to get the id of the control. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, had to use 'this' to get the element id. Code below:
(Updated code to use the wrapper after Pechka's suggestion below)

```
 this.changeSlider = function (data, event) {

        if (data.value === 1) {
            this.wrapper.find('.k-slider-selection').css('background-color', 'red');
        } else if (data.value === 2) {
            this.wrapper.find('.k-slider-selection').css('background-color', 'orange');
        } else if (data.value === 3) {
            this.wrapper.find('.k-slider-selection').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        } else if (data.value === 4) {
            this.wrapper.find('.k-slider-selection').css('background-color', 'green');
        } else if (data.value === 5) {
            this.wrapper.find('.k-slider-selection').css('background-color', 'blue');
        }    
 };
```

Comment: Just posted a short variant ;) anyway glad you found it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the wrapping html element through the **wrapper** field of the widget, which is this in the handler function.

e.g.

```
this.changeSlider = function(){
   this.wrapper.find('.k-slider-selection').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pechka in this instance I wanted to change color of the slider bar. this.wrapper changes the color of the entire container for the slider. Nonetheless useful tip.

Comment: You can change the logic to do find the track and selection, this.wrapper.find('.k-slider-track').css('background','red').

Comment: Perfect Pechka that works absolutely fine. I have updated your code and will do mine as well. Many thanks for your input.